# Informix SQL 11.5 — access to variable in while loop

Tags: stored-procedures, while-loop, informix

I have a while loop like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  PROCEDURE1()

  WHILE EXISTS (SELECT c1 FROM table1)
   --how can to  get c1?
  END WHILE;

END PROCEDURE;
```

Unfortunately, this solution not work:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE  PROCEDURE1()
   Define c1 type1;
   Let c1 = value1;
   WHILE EXISTS (SELECT c1 FROM table1)
   --c1 is not updated after select
    END WHILE;
```

How can I access c1 in while loop?

Comment: Note that Informix 11.50 has been out of service for a while, and 11.70 goes out of service at the end of September 2020.  You should be aiming to upgrade to a newer version of Informix — preferably 14.10 but 12.10 is an alternative, albeit one that will go out of service much quicker than 14.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't completely coherent, which makes it difficult to help you reliably, but this should be close to what you need:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1()

    DEFINE r1 TYPE1;      -- Pick your type here
    FOREACH SELECT c1 INTO r1 FROM Table1
        -- r1 contains the value from the column c1 in the current row
        -- in the table; use it
    END FOREACH

END PROCEDURE;
```

While you could replace the name `r1` with `c1`, that would likely cause confusion.
You can tweak the SELECT statement to meet your needs, adding DISTINCT or passing a value into the procedure and filtering against it, etc.  If there are no matching rows (so what you're looking for doesn't exist), the body of the loop won't be executed.

<sup>*I reserve the right to be missing a semicolon after the SELECT statement.*</sup>